# how to get an index of an element deep inside the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there anyway I could know which link I clicked relatively to the div.grid in the following html?

```
<div class="grid">
  <figure class='grid-item'>
    <figcaption>
      <a>link</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class='grid-item'>
    <figcaption>
      <a>link</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class='grid-item'>
  .....
  </figure>
  ....
</div>
```

I tried:

```
index = $('div.grid').index(this); // returns -1 on every link
index = $(this).parent().parent().parent().index(this); // returns -1
index = $(this).index(); // returns 2 on every link
```

but in the first two cases it returns -1 on every link and on the third 2 (always on every link).

Comment: what is the event listener attached to

Comment: Please clarify... Do you want an index and if so, relative to what? Or, do you just really need to identify the link that was clicked? In other words, what is the reason that you need to identify the link?

Comment: Are you using an event listener on the links? If so, include the code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
var index = $(this).closest('.grid-item').index();
```

For demo:

```js
$('a').click(function(){
  var index = $(this).closest('.grid-item').index();
  alert(index);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <figure class='grid-item'>
    <figcaption>
      <a>link</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class='grid-item'>
    <figcaption>
      <a>link</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class='grid-item'>
    <figcaption>
      <a>link</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get a collection of all the links, you can then get the index based on that collection:

```js
// Gather all the links in the section into an array:
var links = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".grid a"));

// Set up an event handler for them:
links.forEach(function(link){
  link.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // Just get the current link's position in the array
    console.log(links.indexOf(this));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <figure class='grid-item'>
    <figcaption>
      <a>link</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class='grid-item'>
    <figcaption>
      <a>link</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class='grid-item'>
    <figcaption>
      <a>link</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the index of the parent figure element. Not the index of the anchor tag.

```js
jQuery(document).on("click", ".grid a", function() {
  var figure = jQuery(this).parent().parent();
  
  //Retrieve the index of the figure.
  var index = jQuery(figure).index();
  
  alert(index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <figure class='grid-item'>
    <figcaption>
      <a>link</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class='grid-item'>
    <figcaption>
      <a>link</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class='grid-item'>
  </figure>
</div>
```